# Natural deduction LaTeX

Tags: logic

What is the way to write a proof like the one in the image?
[image]

I know how to write all the symbols, but I don't know how to make the rectangle and write like a table. I used this webpage: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/, but I don't like how it displays the proofs.

Comment: In your tex editor (e.g. Texstudio, or Texmaker), you'd probably find a visual menu of symbols on the left with all what you are asking for.

Comment: Otherwise, are you asking how to write in math mode? For example there is a lot of environments that you can use, such as \begin{equation},  \begin{align}, \begin{proof}, etc. So be specific in your question about the difficulty that you are facing.

Comment: I already edited my question.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/) can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using a `tabular` environment. For the simplicity of the code of the proof itself, I defined some new commands. First, an environment `prooftabular` which begins a `tabular` with three columns:

1. The first one automatically displays the number of the row of the proof (you don't have to write anything in it);
2. The second one is automatically in math mode and is thought to be used for steps of the proof;
3. The third one is in text mode and is thought to be used for the justifications of the steps of the proof.

This environment could be used alone to display a proof. However, to add the box with the symbols in the corner, I defined three other commands:

- `\hlineproofbox` adds the horizontal lines of the box with `\cline{2-2}`.
- `\proofboxed` adds the vertical lines around a cell in the box. It takes as an argument the content of the corresponding cell. It only adds the vertical lines with a `\multicolumn{1}{|...|}{...}`.
- `\corner` adds its argument in superscript, in the corner. It should be placed inside of the first `\proofboxed{}`.

These three commands are not so useful in the sense that their content could as well have been placed directly in the table. I just thought the code of the proof was easier to read this way.

Anyway, here's a complete example with your proof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{proofrow}
\newenvironment{prooftabular}{%
    \let\oldarraystretch\arraystretch
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{%
        @{\stepcounter{proofrow}\theproofrow}%
        p{1em}@{}>{\(}l<{\)}>{\quad}l%
    }
    }{%
    \end{tabular}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{\oldarraystretch}
}
\newcommand{\hlineproofbox}{\cline{2-2}}
\newcommand{\proofboxed}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|>{\(}l<{\)}@{\ }|}{#1}}
\newcommand{\corner}[1]{\qquad {}^{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
\forall x, P_1^1(x) \implies P_2^1(x), \forall x . P_2^1(x) \implies P_3^1(x) \vdash \forall x . P_1^1(x) \implies P_3^1(x)
\]
\begin{prooftabular}
    & \forall x . P_1^1(x) \implies P_2^1(x)                        & Prem \\
    & \forall x . P_2^1(x) \implies P_3^1(x)                        & Prem \\
    \hlineproofbox
    & \proofboxed{P_1^1(n) \implies P_2^1(n) \corner{/ \forall n}}  & \(E \ \forall 1\) \\
    & \proofboxed{P_2^1(n) \implies P_3^1(n)}                       & \(E \ \forall 2\) \\
    & \proofboxed{P_1^1(n) \implies P_3^1(n)}                       & Teo \(\alpha \implies \beta, \beta \implies \gamma \vdash \alpha \implies \gamma\) \\
    \hlineproofbox
    & \forall x . P_1^1(x) \implies P_3^1(x)                        & \(\forall x . P_1^1(x) \implies P_2^1(x), \forall x . P_2^1(x) \implies P_3^1(x)\)
\end{prooftabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no issues in writing the symbols commands, then you can use `empheq` package to make a box around some equations (two for simplicity) like this:

[image]

And its code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}
    E=mc^2 \\
    y=ax+b
\end{empheq}
%
\end{document}
```

And of course you can add an asterisk `{align*}` to remove the numbering of equations.

If you want equations numbering left-side, you can use the option `[leqno]` of the `article` class like this

[image]

with some equations numbered and others not (use `\nonumber`), then the code can be

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}
    E=mc^2 \\
    y=ax+b \\
    y_2 = ax+b \nonumber
\end{empheq}
%
\end{document}
```

Well, that's not the perfect answer. It's just some ideas that I am sure others can improve.

Comment: Okay, but how can I add a symbol in the corners and how can I add numbers at the left like in the image of my question?

Comment: That's for left-side numbering. Perhaps for adding symbols in the corner I will leave that for someone else to help. Good luck!